# Best way to generate role based sidebar navigation with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the best way to handle role a based navigation sidebar with React Router?  Right now I am repeating myself by having two sidebars.  I was thinking about mapping over to generate but didn't know if React Router had some functionality already to generate Links based on a Role condition?  If not I am checking if there is a better approach than something like this this below?

Currently I am just hardcoding the Sidebar links instead of dynamically generating.

```

```
const routes = _.map(props.links, (link) => {
    if(someRoleOnUser in link.roles) {
        return (<div><Link .... /></div>);
    } 
})
```

```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same thing.  I might be looking at a further abstraction of letting the DB return a list of links for a given user (so that I could do role and feature filtering on the server). I don't have anything yet on how I will handle it. Hopefully someone else has already tread this ground.